# Facebook Open Graph search for businesses within category and city

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to search for businesses within a city and under a certain category?

For example https://www.facebook.com/search/114952118516947/places-in/180410821995109/places/intersect will show all places under the automotive category in San Fransisco. The first set of numbers is the location id. The second set of numbers is the category id.

Am I able to do the same using the Facebook API using the location and/or category id?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) that allows you to search various types of object.

At present, it only supports a particular type of objects that can be searched. You can find them in the link given above.

I think it doesn't support queries like *Automotives in San Francisco, California* at present. At max, you can search for all the objects at a particular place, using `type=location` and specifying the ID of the place.

For example for Posts at San Francisco, use the following URL with a valid Access Token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&place=114952118516947
```